# What are the major issues while using websocket to get stream of data?

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, apache-kafka

I'm doing it first time. Where am going to read stream of data using websocket.

Here is my code snippet

RsvpApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RsvpApplication {

    private static final String MEETUP_RSVPS_ENDPOINT = "ws://stream.myapi.com/2/rsvps";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RsvpApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner initializeConnection(
        RsvpsWebSocketHandler rsvpsWebSocketHandler) {
            return args -> {
                
                System.out.println("initializeConnection");
                
                WebSocketClient rsvpsSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();

                rsvpsSocketClient.doHandshake(
                    rsvpsWebSocketHandler, MEETUP_RSVPS_ENDPOINT);           
            };
        }
}
```

RsvpsWebSocketHandler

```
@Component
class RsvpsWebSocketHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = 
            Logger.getLogger(RsvpsWebSocketHandler.class.getName());
        
    private final RsvpsKafkaProducer rsvpsKafkaProducer;

    public RsvpsWebSocketHandler(RsvpsKafkaProducer rsvpsKafkaProducer) {    
        this.rsvpsKafkaProducer = rsvpsKafkaProducer;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session,
            WebSocketMessage<?> message) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "New RSVP:\n {0}", message.getPayload());
        
        System.out.println("handleMessage");
        
        rsvpsKafkaProducer.sendRsvpMessage(message);        
    }
}
```

RsvpsKafkaProducer

```
@Component
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class RsvpsKafkaProducer {
  
    private static final int SENDING_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_MS = 10000;

    private final Source source;

    public RsvpsKafkaProducer(Source source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void sendRsvpMessage(WebSocketMessage<?> message) {
        
         System.out.println("sendRsvpMessage");
        source.output()
                .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getPayload())
                        .build(),
                        SENDING_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_MS);   
    }
}
```

As far I know and read about websocket is that, It needs one time connection and stream of data will be flowing continuously until either party (client or server) stops.

I'm building it first time, so trying to cover major scenarios which can come acroos while dealing with 10000+ messages per minute.  Total kafka brokers are two with enough space.

1. What can be done, if connection gets lost and again start consuming messages from webscoket once connected back where it was left in last failure and push messages into further Kafka broker ?
2. What can be done to put on hold websocket to keep pushing messages in broker if it has reached to threshold limit of not processed messages (in broker) ?
3. What can be done, When broker reached to its threshold, run a separate process to check available space in broker to push more messages and give indication to resume pushing messages in kafka broker ?
4. Please share other issues, which needs to be considered while setting up this thing ?

Comment: The broker should stop reading from the websocket when its internal queue is full. That will flow-control the sender into not sending until it starts reading again.

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne, so at threshold, if broker stop consuming messages, Would it be any  impact on handler who is pushing in broker ? And what will happpen with the websocket's stream data, that will also go on hold ? Will stop streaming data ?